# angular-cli caches bitbucket pipeline

Tags: deployment, bitbucket, angular-cli, bitbucket-pipelines

I work with angular 4 and angular-cli. I'm trying to cache node_modules in bitbucket's pipelines.

I tried this

```
definitions:
  caches:
    nodemodules: ~/node_modules
```

or, this

```
definitions:
  caches:
    nodemodules: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules
```

but they did not work, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html), it’s simply:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
```

In other words: simply use “node”. This works for myself in my Bb Pipelines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also tried that one, bat not worked. If I go to the tab caches on the top rightb (in the pipelines page) i find 'You haven't added any dependency caches yet' written. I think the problem is that node_module is generated in the root of the project.